# Best types of valves for dirty services

Tags: valves

I've just started to learn Gate, Globe, Ball, and Butterfly valves.

I'm thinking about "dirty services" now.

Which types of valves are most suitable for dirty services, and what characteristics must the valves have?

Comment: Most valves have descriptions describing the type of duty they are suitable for - what sites or manufacturers have you been checking?

Comment: Really depends on what you mean by "dirty".  Is it cooling water or drain lines at a waste water treatment facility? The biggest concerns with dirty service are fouling and plugging.  Secondarily, you would be concerned about corrosion depending on what is included in the fluid.  The best valves are going to be ball and butterfly since the ball can be designed to be full bore and present no obstruction.  Butterfly are similar, but still have the valve in the flow path.  Globe are awful because they change direction and have the valve components in the flow path.  Gate valves are OK depending..

Comment: on how they are installed.  If the valve is open all the time the pocket at the bottom for the gate to seal into can become clogged with gunk.  All styles of valves can have some amount of modification or specialization for a specific service.  This includes flushes or back flow to prevent accumulation of material.  It also depends on whether the valve is normally open or closed?  Opening a gate valve may be easier than the butterfly since the butterfly has to open "through" the fluid.  Finally, other considerations may be more important like temperature, pressure, and leakage ratings...

Comment: TLDR: it depends